# Magento2.1.1: Theme static pages doesn't load

Tags: theme, cms, magento-2.1.1

I have recently installed Magento 2.1.1 CE with Ultimo theme. Unfortunately predefined CMS static pages doesn't load on home page. Al other static blocks are loading ok (eg. in the footer). The cache was flushed. I reimported several times to make sure that there was no error but without success. Permissions on server are ok.

I don't have any idea why is not working.

Can anyone have a suggestion?

Thank you,
Cornel

Answer (score 0):

Did you re-deploy static files per this http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-static-view.html

That may be needed as well as flushing the cache.